# WSO2AM 4.2.0 login failed while using LDAP secondary user stores

Tags: wso2, ldap, apim

I am trying to configure WSO2AM 4.2.0 to uses LDAP as secondary user store. I have created new user store which pointing to LDAP, and list of users from LDAP could be seen in list of user, role and permission was also set, but when I try to login with LDAP user,it is failed. I try to find the problem from wso2carbon, but nothing log record for those event, meanwhile the `audit.log` give some log record that related to failed login event. After comparing the same log from success login event with PRIMARY user store, I found this difference:

When using secondary user store (LDAP) it seems the value of parameter Target always null. I think that the cause, does somebody know how to solve that problem?

**Success login with PRIMARY user store:**

```
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,917]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-List Target=null Data={"ServiceProviderName":"apim_publisher","Claim Value":"admin","Users":["admin"],"Claim":"wso2.org/claims/username"} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,921]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Values Target=admin Data={"ServiceProviderName":"apim_publisher","Claims":{},"Profile":"default"} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,922]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Values Target=admin Data={"ServiceProviderName":"apim_publisher","Claims":{},"Profile":"default"} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,923]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Values Target=admin Data={"ServiceProviderName":"apim_publisher","Claims":{},"Profile":"default"} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,923]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : admin | Action : LoginStepSuccess | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { "ContextIdentifier" : "6aee430c-eee8-42d0-ad44-f3db75871b75","AuthenticatedUser" : "admin","AuthenticatedUserTenantDomain" : "carbon.super","ServiceProviderName" : "apim_publisher","RequestType" : "oidc","RelyingParty" : "kIU5o46AsimffsYRb9YHGhQC4Moa","AuthenticatedIdP" : "LOCAL","User Agent" : "null","RemoteAddress" : "null","UserStoreDomain" : "PRIMARY" } | Result : Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,923]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : admin@carbon.super | Action : Authenticate | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { Step: 1, IDP: LOCAL, Authenticator:BasicAuthenticator } | Result : Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,925]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-Roles-of-User Target=admin Data={"ServiceProviderName":"apim_publisher","Filter":"*","Roles":["Internal/subscriber","Internal/creator","Internal/publisher","Internal/everyone","Internal/devops","admin","Internal/analytics","Internal/observer","Internal/integration_dev"]} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,925]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-Claim-Values Target=admin Data={"ServiceProviderName":"apim_publisher","Claims":{"wso2.org/claims/username":"admin","wso2.org/claims/userid":"c9be1882-aa24-4576-884d-41ec3ff6bee4","wso2.org/claims/role":"Internal/subscriber,Internal/creator,Internal/publisher,Internal/everyone,Internal/devops,admin,Internal/analytics,Internal/observer,Internal/integration_dev","wso2.org/claims/userprincipal":"admin"}} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,934]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : admin | Action : StoreSession | Data : { {"traceId":"73f7b857-3357-4201-9c35-99f60a6593eb","RememberMe":false,"sessionContextId":"48926f289949e3696802784c4385d873020515e2b8962d098a0d8293496311b1","AuthenticatedUserTenantDomain":"carbon.super","AuthenticatedUser":"admin","LastAccessedTimestamp":1705656805928} } | Result : Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:25,939]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : admin | Action : Login | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { "ContextIdentifier" : "6aee430c-eee8-42d0-ad44-f3db75871b75","AuthenticatedUser" : "admin","AuthenticatedUserTenantDomain" : "carbon.super","ServiceProviderName" : "apim_publisher","RequestType" : "oidc","RelyingParty" : "kIU5o46AsimffsYRb9YHGhQC4Moa","AuthenticatedIdPs" : "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJ3c28yIiwiZXhwIjoxNzA1NjU2ODA4OTIzLCJpYXQiOjE3MDU2NTY4MDU5MjMsImlkcHMiOlt7ImlkcCI6IkxPQ0FMIiwiYXV0aGVudGljYXRvciI6IkJhc2ljQXV0aGVudGljYXRvciJ9XX0.wkLT2T3dYkEpAJ47MnMjsFB3BzQEHiN1DoMmk3_YpvQ","User Agent" : "null","RemoteAddress" : "null","UserStoreDomain" : "PRIMARY" } | Result : Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:33:26,134]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-List Target=null Data={"UserName":"admin","Claim Value":"admin","Users":["admin"],"Claim":"wso2.org/claims/username"} Outcome=Success
```

**Failed login event with SECONDARY user store:**

```
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:36:00,002]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-List Target=null Data={"ServiceProviderName":"apim_publisher","UserName":"admin","Claim Value":"060111544","Claim":"wso2.org/claims/username"} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:36:01,362]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=wso2.system.user Action=Get-User-List Target=null Data={"ServiceProviderName":"apim_publisher","UserName":"admin","Claim Value":"060111544","Claim":"wso2.org/claims/username"} Outcome=Success
TID: [-1234] [2024-01-19 04:36:01,362]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator : 060111544 | Action : Login | Target : ApplicationAuthenticationFramework | Data : { "ContextIdentifier" : "3dd20b79-1922-4c17-92f6-ef3018177e79","ServiceProviderName" : "apim_publisher","RequestType" : "oidc","RelyingParty" : "kIU5o46AsimffsYRb9YHGhQC4Moa","StepNo" : "1","User Agent" : "null","RemoteAddress" : "null","UserStoreDomain" : "INTRANET" } | Result : Failed
```

I try to configuring LDAP as secondary user store in wso2am 4.2.0, I expect could logged in with LDAP, but it still failed when login with LDAP user.

Comment: Did you try to login with admin user in LDAP ?

Answer (score 0):

If a user is not able to log in, it may be due to one or some of the following reasons:

1. Credentials are incorrect/invalid.
2. Users do not have enough permissions to log in and work.
3. User store has not been configured properly.
4. Case-sensitivity of the username.

I assume that in your case, you have missed assigning roles to the users. You should add **Internal/creator**, **Internal/publisher**, and **Internal/subscriber** roles to log in to the publisher and DevPortal.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but even those 3 mandatory roles already assigned to user, login still fails